# Retornar o ultimo ID com PDO em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso pegar o ultimo id inserido, ja tentei utilizar o lasInsertId mas não estou conseguindo, não sei se executei errado ou etc, mas aqui está o código da minha conexão e funções de PDO. O erro fica sendo no GetUltimoId().

```
//função para fazer conexão com o banco de dados
private function Conectar(){

    $options = array(
        //trasforma o padrao do banco para utf8
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8",
        //traz algum alerta de erro
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
    );
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->banco}", $this->user, $this->senha, $options);

    return $link;
}

//função que executa a query
function ExecuteSQL($query, array $params = NULL){
    $this->obj = $this->Conectar()->prepare($query);

    // verificando a quantidade de parametros passados na url
    if(@count($params) > 0){
        foreach($params as $key => $value){
            $this->obj->bindvalue($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $this->obj->execute();
}
//função para listar os meus elementos
function ListarDados(){
    return $this->obj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

//função para mostrar um quantidade de dados
function TotalDados(){
   return $this->obj->rowCount(); 
}

//função que armazena os itens dentro de um array
function GetItens(){
    return $this->itens;
}

function GetUltimoID(){
    return $this->obj->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: Parece que você está executando o método `lastInsertId` no retorno de `$this->Conectar()->prepare`, que será uma instância de `PDOStatement`. Você deve chamar o método na instância da sua conexão ou transação.

Comment: Se eu mudar para $this->Conectar()->lasInsertId(); Ele me retorna o id 0

Comment: Porque aí você está criando uma nova conexão. Tente analisar o código que está escrevendo e entender, de fato, o que foi feito.

Comment: E é por isto que estou pedindo ajudo, não sei como estruturar, pois estou aprendendo e nas videos aulas que vi ele não explica direito,  não sei como chamar esta instância

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na sua chamada ao `lastInsertId`. Você está chamando o método em `$this->obj`, que definiu como o retorno de `prepare`:

```
$this->obj = $this->Conectar()->prepare($query);
```

O retorno do `prepare` é uma instância de [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php) e essa classe não possui o método `lastInsertId`. Você deve chamar tal método diretamente sobre sua conexão ou transação.

Seu método `Conectar` retorna sempre uma nova conexão com o banco a cada chamada. Isso é bastante incomum e provavelmente desnecessário, visto que você pode reaproveitar a conexão. Assim, você pode armazenar a conexão:

```php
private function Conectar(){

    if (!isset($this->link)) {
        $options = array(
            //trasforma o padrao do banco para utf8
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8",
            //traz algum alerta de erro
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
        );
        $this->link = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->banco}", $this->user, $this->senha, $options);
    }

    return $this->link;
}
```

Assim a conexão será feita apenas uma vez por instância e em toda a chamada de `Conectar` será retornado o mesmo objeto. Feito isso, você poderá alterar o método que busca o último id:

```php
function GetUltimoID(){
    return $this->Conectar()->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: So fiquei com duvida com duvida do $this->link, eu não definici em nenhum momento a variavel link, quando coloco ela pela primeira vez com $this ele ja instancia ela ?

Comment: Não, isso é feito dentro do `if`, quando ela não existir ainda.

Comment: Ata, muito Obrigado